# Count how many number are there from $1$ to $N$ who have all $10$ digits in it at least once.

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> Count how many number are there from $1$ to $N$ who have all $10$ digits in it **at least** once.

Can we have a generalized method to solve this problem?

Comment: A similar one is : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2227807/number-of-integers-containing-every-digit-atleast-once?noredirect=1#comment4580974_2227807

Comment: @JaideepKhare That question doesn't have a proper answer yet !    
The answer given there is counting such numbers $\leq 10^n-1$.. But I need to count from $L$ to $R$.

Comment: That's why I couldn't flag it as a duplicate. I hope this one gets an answer.

Comment: @MarcusStuhr I can solve this for $N = 10^d$ but how to do for any arbitrary $N$?

Comment: If you can count from $1$ to $N$, you can count from $1$ to $L-1$ and subtract from the count from $1$ to $R$ to get from $L$ to $R$.

Answer (score 2):

Let me try another, more detailed answer:

We will call the amount of numbers $\leq N$ that contain all digits $A(N)$. And we say that $N$ has $d(N)$ digits. The smallest number of this kind is $1023456789$, since $0$ can not be the leading digit.

> Therefore $A(N) = 0$ if $N < 1023456789$ ($d(N) < 10$).

First, we will find $A(N)$ depending on the number of digits of $N$:

There are $d$ digits. The *special* digit $0$ may be placed at $d-1$ positions. The $1$ at $d-1$ positions, the $2$ at $d-2$ positions and so on to $9$. Now we have $d-10$ *positions* left without digit. Let us approximate that **any** digit may be placed on the *free positions*. This is just an approximation, since the $0$ must not stand at the leading position and some double counting may be included. However, the error is rather small, especially for big $N$. Everybody may feel free to post a solution to this error in the comments. We combine all this and get

> $$ A(d) \approx (d-1)(d-1)(d-2)...(d-9) \cdot 10^{d-10} = (d-1)\dfrac{(d-1)!}{(d-10)!} \cdot 10^{d-10}. $$

With this information we can now compose $A(N)$.

> $d(N)$ given by $$ d(N) = \lfloor \log_{10}N \rfloor + 1. $$

Therefore we have as good approximation

$$ A(N) \approx \log_{10}N\dfrac{(\log_{10}N)!}{(\log_{10}N-10)!} \cdot 10^{\log_{10}N-10} $$

and since $\log_{10}N-10 = \log_{10}{\frac{N}{10^{10}}}$:

> $$ A(N) \approx \log_{10}N\dfrac{(\log_{10}N)!}{(\log_{10}N-10)!} \cdot \frac{N}{10^{10}}. $$

Answer (score -1):

The first easy use case, is if $N$ is less than 10 digits. In this case, the answer is obviously 0.

Next, take a look at $N$ with 10 digits. The first guess is that there are $10!$ possibilities, however, this would be wrong, as 0 cannot be a leading number. Therefore it would be $9*9!$.

My guess is that you could extrapolate a recursive algorithm using $N_10 = $9*9!$.

Comment: Do you think this solves the problem even by 1% ! ?

Comment: And my question wasn't about $N$ with $d$ digits :\ :\ 
Solve this for $N = 12245199423$ :\ :\ How many such numbers are there $\leq N$ with such property? :\

Comment: You never stated that you had a specific value of $N$. There's no way I could have formulated an answer for that

Comment: @0123456789101112 you did not mention this aspect of your question above...

Answer (score -2):

Hint: For a number with $d \geq 10$ digits, there are 
$$ 10! \cdot \prod_{n=0}^{d-11}(d+1-n) $$
combinations of numbers that include all digits. But this **does** include some double counting.

Also note: The number of digits of your number is
$$ \lfloor\log_{10}N \rfloor + 1. $$

Comment: How did you obtain this?